How to preserve custom changes in Core DNS(Kube-DNS) in OKE(Oracle Cloud Kubernetes)?
I have created an Enhanced Cluster of Kubernetes(OKE) in Oracle Cloud (OCI). In the cluster I am required to do some communication from pods to some VM instances outside OKE but in the same VCN subnet in which my pods lie. I want to do this communication not IP based but with local domains.
To achieve this I am trying to put my ip domain mapping in hosts block in my core-dns configmap already automatically created by OKE.
Issue : Every time I make this edit entry in configmap and do a proper rollout, after a regular period (say around 12 hours or so), it gets overridden back to its original state. I am not able to conclude what is causing this behavior as this is an enhanced cluster and not a Basic one.
Is there any other recommended way to do this host mapping so that custom changes will get preserved?
Sharing my Coredns configmap edit code below (custom code starts and End mentioned in below YAML):
kubectl edit cm coredns -n kube-system
data:
  Corefile: |-
    .:53 {
      errors

      health {

        lameduck 5s

      }

      ready

      kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {

        pods insecure

        fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa

      }

      prometheus :9153

      forward . /etc/resolv.conf

      cache 30

      loop

      reload

      loadbalance
#Custom Code Starts
      hosts {

        10.110.2.60 citus.exotel.local

        10.110.2.60 citus-coordinator-master.exotel.local

        10.110.2.252 citus-coordinator-replica.exotel.local

        10.110.2.96 citus-worker-0.exotel.local

        10.110.2.59 redis.exotel.local

        10.110.2.8 kafka.exotel.local

        10.110.2.8 kafka-0.exotel.local

        10.110.2.250 kafka-1.exotel.local

        10.110.2.142 kafka-2.exotel.local

        fallthrough

      }
#Custom Code Ends 
    }

    import custom/*.server

kind: ConfigMap

metadata:


  name: coredns


